# Android: How to switch to Activity that has already been created

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to Android programming.
What I want to do is to swith to an another activity that has already been created.
Suppose I started Activity B and move from  Activity A to Activity B, and then I pressed back button and move back to Activity A.
Now I want to switch to Activity B when a countdown timer is done.

`ActivityA.java`

```
  private void startTimer() {
        ...
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // force the user to move on to Activity B
            // if the user haven't started Activity B, just start it
            if (!mHasActivityBStarted) {
                Intent intent =
                        new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // how can I switch to ActivityB that has been created?
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I suggest to google for "android activity launch mode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) documentation

> **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT**
>
> ```
> public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
> ```
>
> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's
>   history stack if it is already running.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of four activities: A, B, C,
>   D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the
>   history stack, with this resulting order: A, C, D, B. This flag will
>   be ignored if FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is also specified.

In your case, you can switch between `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` without finishing or recreating them.

Put it together.

**ActivityA**

```
// Call this method when users press a button on ActivityA to go to ActivityB.
public void goToActivityB(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// When users press a button from ActivityB, ActivityA will be bring to front and this method will be called by Android.
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // Write your logic code here
}
```

**ActivityB**

```
// Call this method when users press on a button in ActivityB
public void backToActivityA(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// When users press a button from ActivityA, ActivityB will be bring to front and this method will be called by Android.
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // Write your logic code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think it solves my problem but I still don't get `onNewIntent` what's the difference between `onCreate`

Comment: `onNewIntent` is called when an activity is already in the backstack and you want to start it again without creating. `onCreate` is called only one when an activity first created.